# xslt locate node with specific string and display siblings values

Tags: xml, xslt

First, I'm terribly new at this so your patience is appreciated.

Here is part of the tree:

```
<root>
<dynamic-metadata>
    <name>alternative-title</name>
</dynamic-metadata>    
<dynamic-metadata>
    <name>category</name>
    <value>General</value>
    <value>Academic</value>
    <value>Business</value>
</dynamic-metadata>
<dynamic-metadata>
    <name>primary-nav</name>
    <value>Top bar</value>
</dynamic-metadata>
</root>
```

Given that there are several nodes for 'dynamic-metadata', how would I write the xslt to:

1. Locate the specific node with the string of 'category', then
2. Loop through name=category's siblings to retrieve and display the text contained in the "value" nodes?

Ideally, I'm attempting to create an output that has:
Categories: value(string), value(string), value(string)

Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

the `dynamic-metadata[name='category']` template below should do what you want, with adaptions (you haven't given details about the actual XSLT you are using): (BTW, I had to fix up your XML, it was not well formed)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="dynamic-metadata[name='category']">
    <output>Categories:<xsl:for-each select="value">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="position() != last()">
                    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Immensely helpful! Thank you so much for your assistance.

Comment: Yes, it led me to my answer and I got the output I was hoping for. Thx again